# Can not get full screen with full screen exclusive mode

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen

I want to put JFrame in fullscreen and change a display mode into 1280*720 but the JFrame is not full screen.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqSAa.png)

Here is my code

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
f.setUndecorated(true);
f.setResizable(false);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
if (device.isFullScreenSupported()) {
    device.setFullScreenWindow(f);
    if (device.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
        try {
            DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(1280, 720, 32, 60);
            device.setDisplayMode(dm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } else {
        System.err.println("Change display mode not supported");
    }
} else {
    System.err.println("Full screen not supported");
}
```

Comment: Works for me, Windows 7, Java 8.  Looks like you're using Windows 10?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, i'm using Windows 10, I have tried to run on Windows 8 but it's not works also.

Comment: @NoppawitThairungroj Then take a look at the linked "possible duplicate", that seems to be reasonable option

Comment: @MadProgrammer I can change the display mode with out any error but it's still not full screen, so I don't think my question is duplicated ?
Sorry if i wrong, i'm a beginner.

Comment: But based on you screen shot, it's not changing the screen mode

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's already changed, my screen resolution is 1920*1080 there's also a windows popup warn about 1280*720 isn't a best resolution.

Comment: Is my solution working for you under Win10?

Comment: @Leet-Falcon No, it only extends the frame with gray space but not fit the frame with the screen.

Comment: 1280, 720, 32, 60 is listed in your device.getDisplayModes() ?

Comment: Yes, it is in the listed of device.getDisplayModes()

Comment: You could try using `DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN` for the refresh mode and may `DisplayMode.BIT_DEPTH_MULTI`

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is, your graphics card and/or video driver and/or monitor can't support the `DisplayMode` you're trying to use

It's probably preferable to use one of the `DisplayMode`s which is listed by 
`GraphicsDevice#getDisplayModes`, for example...

```
DisplayMode[] modes = device.getDisplayModes();
for (DisplayMode mode : modes) {
    System.out.println(mode.getWidth() + "x" + mode.getHeight() + " " + mode.getBitDepth() + " @ " + mode.getRefreshRate());
}
```

Which, on my machine outputs

```
640x480 32 @ 60
640x480 32 @ 75
720x480 32 @ 60
720x480 32 @ 75
720x576 32 @ 60
720x576 32 @ 75
800x600 32 @ 60
800x600 32 @ 75
1024x768 32 @ 60
1024x768 32 @ 75
1152x864 32 @ 75
1280x720 32 @ 60
1280x720 32 @ 75
1280x768 32 @ 60
1280x768 32 @ 75
1280x800 32 @ 60
1280x800 32 @ 75
1280x960 32 @ 60
1280x960 32 @ 75
1280x1024 32 @ 60
1280x1024 32 @ 75
1360x768 32 @ 60
1366x768 32 @ 60
1600x900 32 @ 60
1600x1024 32 @ 60
1600x1200 32 @ 60
1680x1050 32 @ 59
1680x1050 32 @ 60
1920x1080 32 @ 59
1920x1080 32 @ 60
1920x1200 32 @ 59
1920x1200 32 @ 60
```

As you can see, `1280x720 32 @ 60` is listed as one of the available modes and your code works fine on my machine without modification.

I did try using `DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(1280, 720, DisplayMode.BIT_DEPTH_MULTI, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);`, but it failed with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid display mode`

So, then I thought, bugger it, I'll pick out the "most" likely matches and just try them until one sticks...

```
try {
    List<DisplayMode> matchingModes = new ArrayList<>(25);

    DisplayMode[] modes = device.getDisplayModes();
    for (DisplayMode mode : modes) {
        if (mode.getWidth() == 1280 && mode.getHeight() == 720) {
            matchingModes.add(mode);
        }
    }

    if (!matchingModes.isEmpty()) {
    for (DisplayMode mode : matchingModes) {
        try {
            device.setDisplayMode(mode);
            System.out.println(mode.getWidth() + "x" + mode.getHeight() + " " + mode.getBitDepth() + " @ " + mode.getRefreshRate());
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    } else {
        System.err.println("!! No matching modes available");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which end up using `1280x720, 32 @ 60`.  Now I also thought you might be able to sort the list in order of bit deepness and refresh rate, but I'll leave that to you to decide and work out

This is basically my test code...

```
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JavaApplication155 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setUndecorated(true);
        f.add(new TestPane());
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment
                        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        if (device.isFullScreenSupported()) {
            device.setFullScreenWindow(f);
            if (device.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
                try {
                    List<DisplayMode> matchingModes = new ArrayList<>(25);

                    DisplayMode[] modes = device.getDisplayModes();
                    for (DisplayMode mode : modes) {
                        if (mode.getWidth() == 1280 && mode.getHeight() == 720) {
                            matchingModes.add(mode);
                        }
                    }

                    if (!matchingModes.isEmpty()) {
                        for (DisplayMode mode : matchingModes) {
                            try {
                                device.setDisplayMode(mode);
                                System.out.println(mode.getWidth() + "x" + mode.getHeight() + " " + mode.getBitDepth() + " @ " + mode.getRefreshRate());
                                break;
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.err.println("!! No matching modes available");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("Change display mode not supported");
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("Full screen not supported");
        }
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TestPane.this).dispose();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            String text = getWidth() + "x" + getHeight();
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2;
            g.drawString(text, x, y + fm.getAscent());

            GraphicsDevice device = GraphicsEnvironment
                            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();

            DisplayMode mode = device.getDisplayMode();
            text = mode.getWidth() + "x" + mode.getHeight() + " " + mode.getBitDepth() + " @ " + mode.getRefreshRate();
            x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            y += fm.getHeight();
            g.drawString(text, x, y + fm.getAscent());
        }

    }

}
```

As mentioned in [the Display Mode trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/displaymode.html)

> When choosing a display mode for your application, you may want to keep a list of preferred display modes, then choose the best one from the list of available display modes.

Tested on Windows 10, Java 8